# Download using Yii::app()->request->SendFile returns corrupted file

Tags: php, yii, download, yii1.x, sendfile

I've been trying to download my uploaded file from a specific directory like this:

```
Yii::app()->request->SendFile($model->statement, 
                        file_get_contents($path.$model->statement)
                        );
```

It recognizes the file and downloaded it with the correct name and format, but all I get instead of a 74KB file, is a 1KB corrupted file. Tried other documents such as .doc, .pdf, still the same.

I am not entirely sure about what the file_get_contents actually does as I took this from an example I found.

The file to be downloaded was previously uploaded using

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'statement'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'statement', array('size' => 36, 'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'statement'); ?>
</div>
```

in the _form.php and adjusted the actionCreate in the controller:

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{
    $model=new Witness;
    $model->ip_id = $id;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/modules/iris/statements';
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        mkdir($path);
    }   

    if(isset($_POST['Witness']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Witness'];

        if (@!empty($_FILES['Witness']['name']['statement'])) {
            $model->statement = $_POST['Witness']['statement'];
            if ($model->validate(array('statement'))) {
                $model->statement = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'statement');
            } else {
                $model->statement = '';
            }

            $model->statement->saveAs($path . '/' . time() . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($model->statement)));

            //$model->doc_type = $model->statement->getType();
            //$model->doc_size = $model->statement->getSize();
        }

        $model->statement = time() . '_' . str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($model->statement));


        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('ip/view','id'=>$model->ip_id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

The uploaded files can be opened with no problem. Any idea of why the download corrupted? Do I have to specify the type/size of the file first before downloading?

Answer (score 0):

With a 1kb file it sounds like your server is throwing a php error after the headers have been set.

Open the downloaded file with text editor and check the contents.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Opened the file with a text editor, it shows the $path of the file. So now I know file_get_contents actually overwrites my file with its argument. I better recheck the arguments for the SendFile function.

Comment: Still can't find a way to get it right. Is (public void sendFile(string $fileName, string $content, string $mimeType=NULL, boolean $terminate=true) function can be used for this? And what should the argument for $content be?

Comment: The 2nd param should be the content of your file. Your example code looks correct. Try `var_dump(file_get_contents($path.$model->statement));exit;` and see what get's outputted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I have a found another solution for this. Look at my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution instead of using the SendFile function. Put this in the view file to generate the download link:

```
CHtml::link('Click to download file', array('ip/download&id='.$model->file_id));
```

where 'ip' the the model name. This will pass file_id to the function actionDownload created in the controller.php:

```
public function downloadFile($fullpath){
    if(!empty($fullpath)){
        header("Content-type:application/pdf"); //for pdf file
        //header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15');
        //if you want to read text file using text/plain header
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fullpath).'"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullpath));
        readfile($fullpath);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}

public function actionDownload($id){
    $model=Ip::model()->findByPk($id);
    $path = Yii::app()->basePath . 'location of file to be downloaded'.$model->filename;
    $this->downloadFile($path);
}
```

This should download the file completely. Don't worry about the content-type, I have tried all common file types (.pdf, .doc, .ppt, .png, .jpg), all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2, a [sendFile()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendFile()-detail) signature is

```php
public $this sendFile ( $filePath, $attachmentName = null, $options = [] )
```

Sending a file:

```php
Yii::$app->response->sendFile('test.zip');
```

For those, who get full files, but still corrupted:

> You should check if other php files are printing output, sometimes whitespace after closing PHP tags can cause problems.

[From here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/17989#issuecomment-617817180)

Comment: This question is about Yii 1.1, your answer is for Yii 2.

Comment: @rob006, when I answered, there was no `yii1.x` tag, only `yii`.

Comment: OP is using `Yii::app()`, so this is obviously Yii 1.1. Your answer may be confusing, because `sendFile()` has different signature in Yii 2 than in Yii 1.1.

Comment: No, it isn't obviously. And I pointed out that first part of my answer is for Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the arguments list of [`sendFile`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#sendFile-detail), you can see that 3rd parameter is `mimeType`. In fact, you do not present a HTTP headers response, so my prima vista suggestion to you is to try explicitly specify the `Content-Type` response header:

```
Yii::app()->request->sendFile(
   "Youfile.pdf",
   file_get_contents('path/to/file'), 
   'application/pdf'
);
```